# Entity Core Distinct on different field as the where field

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I need to do a select on all records from a certain date but receive a distinct on another field.

Here is what I currently have before trying to get distinct results.

```
var entity = _context.ClientOrder
            .Where(s => s.DateScanned == datetime)
            .OrderBy(s => s.Sequence)
            .Include(s => s.ClientVehicle)
            .ThenInclude(s => s.ClientDetails)
            .ToList();
```

I was hoping for something like this

```
var entity = _context.ClientOrder
            .Where(s => s.DateScanned == datetime)
            .Select(s => s.GroupId)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(s => s.Sequence)
            .Include(s => s.ClientVehicle)
            .ThenInclude(s => s.ClientDetails)
            .ToList();
```

As per a suggestion I am now trying to use GroupBy() but it doesn't seem to work. Is my syntax wrong?

```
var entity = _context.ClientOrder
            .GroupBy(s => s.GroupId)
            .Where(s => s.DateScanned == datetime)
            .OrderBy(s => s.Sequence)
            .Include(s => s.ClientVehicle)
            .ThenInclude(s => s.ClientDetails)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: " distinct on another field" sounds like GroupBy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: `Distinct()` will check the values of every property in the class and eliminates the duplicate if the values are same for every property. If anyone of the property value is different it considers as a different record

Comment: Hey @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I am now trying to use GroupBy but its not working. Can you please confirm my syntax or what it should look like?

Comment: The output of GroupBy (key, collection) pairs.  Each distinct GroupId may have lots of rows.